# How to block images in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I am using [Watir](http://watir.github.io/) for a data fetching job where I don't need any images to be loaded. Is it possible to block them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be:

```
        profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
        profile['webkit.webprefs.loads_images_automatically'] = false

        @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```

See: http://watir.github.io/docs/chrome/

Comment: `options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new` and then `options.add_preference('webkit.webprefs.loads_images_automatically', false)` worked for me too

Comment: do we know where could we see the list of all such options?

Comment: i find this link for list: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/webkit.webpreferences.allowsanimatedimagelooping?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14

Answer (score 3):

Use :

```
webkit: { webprefs: { loads_images_automatically: false } } or profile: { default_content_setting_values: { images: 2 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable displaying images in the browser Watir drives manually, and then run Watir script. As far as I know, you can not do it from Watir itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
prefs = {
    :profile => {
        :managed_default_content_settings => { 
          :images => 2
        }
    }
}

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs
```

Answer (score 0):

- Watir 7.1.0
- Selenium 4.1.0

```rb
prefs = {
  profile: {
    managed_default_content_settings: {
      images: 2
    }
  }
}

Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: { prefs: prefs })
```

If you need to specify the URL of the Selenium server/grid:

```
Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: { prefs: prefs }, url: url)
```