# Can Watir instruct the browser to skip loading images entirely?

Tags: web-scraping, watir

I'm using [watir](https://watir.github.io) to scrape a slow Web site for simple pieces of textual data.  I'd like to save my time and the server's bandwidth by entirely skipping the (multiple, slow) images each page needlessly sends my Watir-controlled browser.

I realize it's up to the browser and not Watir, but I wonder if there's a convenient way to get Watir to reconfigure the browser to not load images that session.  I could not readily find an answer googling.

Comment: Oh, looks like this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386318/how-to-block-images-in-watir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Block images in watir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386318/how-to-block-images-in-watir)